# Sharepoint REST endpoint access denied error while access through postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to access the SharePoint REST service and trying to upload objects using the curl command. I have followed the steps from this [blog](http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/).

I was able to get pass through steps until getting the access token. After that when I tried to access the REST point **https://<domain_name>.sharepoint.com/Internal_Documents/_api/web/**. I'm getting access denied error with HTTP status code 403 Forbidden.

```
Response 
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you have at least read permission on that site

Comment: I understand that you are referring to this one. I have given this value as full control.

<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>

Please point me. If there is any method to test whether access is there or not?

Comment: there web where you are trying to use API is it a subsite? If yes add read permission to SiteCollection scope http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection

Comment: No, I am not trying to access any subsites. Trying to access(Read/Write) only the main site contents.

Comment: Do I need to provide any user credentials with the request? Or will it be based on the registered app's authorization scope?

Answer (score -1):

According to the error message, the required resources are not properly authorized.
Check whether your authorized web and the web requested by your rest are the same.